# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Google Chrome embed HTML play wmv, mov, mpeg2

Tags: google-chrome, video, embed, video.js

Would I know if any method could help to embed the wmv, mov and mpeg2 video to a webpage in ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Does video.js can perform the work?

I would like to use a web browser locally to make those video file plays in different region in ubuntu using Google Chrome in a webpage.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively. The HTML5 tech can play what the browser can play - webm, ogv and h264/mp4 (maybe not even the latter on Linux?). The Flash tech will play a couple more formats, notably flv. There are some additional [tech plugins](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/Plugins#playback-techs-support-media-from-different-sources) that add support for further types.

Comment: Thanks i have tried videojs-java but it doesn't work, i compiled and it cannot preview in videojs, any expert have experience on this?  (I am running on ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Comment: I doubt that's widely used. The plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/Afterster/videojs-java/issues) might be a better place to get help.

Comment: So, may i know if there is any experience on playing mpeg2/mov/avi on html5? recently chrome block NPAPI may that is not possible for vlc plugin, am i right? Should i do local streaming and do the live streaming to the video tag in HTML5?

Comment: Can you not convert the videos to a standard web video format?

Comment: I have to convert it on the fly, so i have used https://github.com/derolf/transcoder this project for help on the fly transcoding, but seems not quite work due to update of Flask